# How to solve "Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)"

Tags: angular, npm, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer, ng2-pdf-viewer

I'm trying to use [`ng2-pdf-viewer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) package.

I have added this module to `app.module.ts` as like that:

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

imports: [
    PdfViewerModule,
]
```

But I got these types of errors:

```
Error: ./node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/fesm2015/ng2-pdf-viewer.mjs 194:29-49
Can't import the named export 'VerbosityLevel' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/fesm2015/ng2-pdf-viewer.mjs 791:12-21
Can't import the named export 'ViewChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/fesm2015/ng2-pdf-viewer.mjs 690:39-51
Can't import the named export 'debounceTime' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

NodeJs: v16.18.1

Npm: v8.19.2

Angular Cli: 11.2.13

OS: linux x64(Ubuntu)

I have tried these:

- Removed `node_modules` and `npm install`
- Removed `package-lock.json` and `npm install`
- Cleared npm cache by using `npm cache clean`
- Tried to import the module to `app.module.ts` as `import * PdfViewerModule from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';`
- Tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69343125/284199
- I've also tried `[ngx-extended-pdf-viewer]` package as alternative.
  But nothing changes.

What is wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: have you found the issue or the solution?
If yes, post the answer so you will help other people in the future