# Radix UI with react Can't import the named export 'Anchor' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: reactjs, npm, radix-ui

Trying to add Radix UI with react throws a bunch of errors:

```
Primitive.tsx:45 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Primitive.tsx:45:1
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at ./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-primitive/dist/index.mjs (Primitive.tsx:44:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-dismissable-layer/dist/index.js (Direction.tsx:26:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-tooltip/dist/index.mjs (Tabs.tsx:283:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/@radix-ui/themes/dist/esm/theme.js (theme.tsx:1:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/@radix-ui/themes/dist/esm/index.js (index.ts:1:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at Module.<anonymous> (NotFound.js:13:1)
at ./src/Seila.js (Seila.js:73:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at Module.<anonymous> (Seila.js:73:1)
at ./src/Table.js (Table.js:48:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at Module.<anonymous> (index.css:8:1)
at ./src/App.js (App.js:39:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at Module.<anonymous> (index.css:82:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.js:25:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at 1 (useFetch.js:43:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
at main.chunk.js:1:71
```

That's error 1

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at 4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at 8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at 8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at <anonymous>:2:315627
at <anonymous>:2:324225
at <anonymous>:2:324229
at e.onload (index.js:1:1)
```

Error 2

```
./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-tooltip/dist/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Anchor' from non EcmaScript module 
(only default export is available)
```

Error 3

Now here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import '@radix-ui/themes/styles.css';
import  {Theme}  from '@radix-ui/themes';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-            
query'

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Theme>
          <App />
      </Theme>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is the only implementation I did.
The instructions on the page are pretty simple as well so I don't know where I could've gone wrong
I've tried most of the stuff on the internet and nothing works..
Any ideas on how to tackle the issue?

Comment: Please checkout: "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Have a look at this other [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343038/cant-import-the-named-export-xxxx-from-non-ecmascript-module-only-default-expo) question and see if there is anything helpful in the answers.

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am getting the same